# r creating an adjacency matrix from columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, graph, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I am interested in testing some network visualization techniques but before trying those functions I want to build an adjacency matrix (from, to) using the dataframe which is as follows.

```
 Id   Gender   Col_Cold_1  Col_Cold_2  Col_Cold_3  Col_Hot_1  Col_Hot_2   Col_Hot_3  
 10   F         pain       sleep        NA         infection  medication  walking
 14   F         Bump       NA           muscle     NA         twitching   flutter
 17   M                    pain         hemoloma   Callus     infection   
 18   F         muscle                  pain                  twitching   medication
```

My goal is to create an adjacency matrix as follows

```
1) All values in columns with keyword Cold will contribute to the rows  
2) All values in columns with keyword Hot will contribute to the columns
```

For example, `pain, sleep, Bump, muscle, hemaloma` are cell values under the columns with keyword **Cold** and they will form the rows and cell values such as `infection, medication, Callus, walking, twitching, flutter` are under columns with keywords **Hot** and this will form the columns of the association matrix.

The final desired output should appear like this:

```
           infection  medication  walking  twitching  flutter  Callus
     pain  2          2           1        1                   1
    sleep  1          1           1
     Bump                                  1          1
   muscle             1                    1
 hemaloma  1                                                   1
```

- `[pain, infection]` = 2 because the association between pain and infection occurs twice in the original dataframe: once in row 1 and again in row 3.
- `[pain, medication]`=2 because association between pain and medication occurs twice once in row 1 and again in row 4.

Any suggestions or advice on producing such an association matrix is much appreciated thanks.

**Reproducible Dataset**

```
df = structure(list(id = c(10, 14, 17, 18), Gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), Col_Cold_1 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", "Bump", "muscle", "pain"), class = "factor"), Col_Cold_2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "NA", "pain", "sleep"), class = "factor"), Col_Cold_3 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("NA", "hemaloma", "muscle", "pain" ), class = "factor"), Col_Hot_1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Callus", "NA", "infection"), class = "factor"), Col_Hot_2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("infection", "medication", "twitching"), class = "factor"), Col_Hot_3 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("", "flutter", "medication", "walking" ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "Gender", "Col_Cold_1", "Col_Cold_2", "Col_Cold_3", "Col_Hot_1", "Col_Hot_2", "Col_Hot_3" ), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There's a ton of info on creating adjacency matrices already: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14850986/1152809), [two](https://www.r-bloggers.com/graph-from-sparse-adjacency-matrix/), [three (pdf)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=0ahUKEwimt5nt-P7QAhVr64MKHUdpDgEQFghWMAo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.londonr.org%2Fdownload%2F%3Fid%3D97&usg=AFQjCNFemmTxQFHFidF4mzLWZWw43yuqmA&sig2=SC6hY1bLpOjmiEwvsxOfUw). What have your tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make the dataset into a "tidy" form, then use `xtabs`.  First, some cleaning up:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)  # Convert factors to characters
df[df == "NA" | df == "" | is.na(df)] <- NA  # Make all blanks NAs
```

Now, tidy the dataset:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
out <- do.call(rbind, sapply(grep("^Col_Cold", names(df), value = T), function(x){
  vars <- c(x, grep("^Col_Hot", names(df), value = T))
  setNames(gather_(select(df, one_of(vars)), 
    key_col = x,
    value_col = "value",
    gather_cols = vars[-1])[, c(1, 3)], c("cold", "hot"))
}, simplify = FALSE))
```

The idea is to "pair" each of the "cold" columns with each of the "hot" columns to make a long dataset. `out` looks like this:

```
out
#        cold        hot
# 1      pain  infection
# 2      Bump       <NA>
# 3      <NA>     Callus
# 4    muscle       <NA>
# 5      pain medication
# ...
```

Finally, use `xtabs` to make the desired output:

```
xtabs(~ cold + hot, na.omit(out))
#           hot
# cold       Callus flutter infection medication twitching walking
#   Bump          0       1         0          0         1       0
#   hemaloma      1       0         1          0         0       0
#   muscle        0       1         0          1         2       0
#   pain          1       0         2          2         1       1
#   sleep         0       0         1          1         0       1
```

Comment: that worked but my original dataset does not have columns with keyword `Cold` in the order `Col_Cold_x`, there are different patterns of word `Cold` for example there are few columns like this `Col_Cold` and few columns with column names `Col_Cold_xy1....Col_Cold_xy10` and few  columns with column names `Col_Cold1.....Col_Cold10` and some columns with pattern `Col_Cold_Combine1......Col_Cold_Combine10` etc....so incorporating these various column combinations is causing some problems. Any advice on how may i change the code ? Thanks Wong.

Comment: In this case we can use `grep` to find the relevant columns.  See edits.