# How can i create a directed adjacency matrix based on some conditions from my data frame in R?

Tags: r, matrix, networking, graph, adjacency-matrix

I have a dataset of albums from 60s to 2010s and my goal is a network to visualize the influences beteen albums over the years. I want to create an adjacency matrix based on two variables conditions: genre and release date. Genre is character and my idea was: **x** is influenced by **y**, **if** (x,y) = have at least 1 word in common in the genre column **and** x is following y in date of release.

That's my first question here, so probably is not in the right format. Anyway every suggest would be helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41214012/r-creating-an-adjacency-matrix-from-columns-in-a-dataframe?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you're talking is a graph on the cartesian plane. An adjacency-matrix is used to store graphs with nodes and connections, like this:

[image]

rather than this:

[image]

if you want to store a cartesian you can try creating a 2-d matrix or keep a list/array of coordinates.

Comment: i understand what you say, so the 2 dimensions could be the string similarity and the time. Do yyou know how to write it in R?

Comment: I personally do not know R very well, but there are plenty of great resources online. If you just google plotting an XY plane you can find many results. One such result is: https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/graphics/html/plot.html.