# Implement MCL (Markov Cluster Algorithm) in R for graph data

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization, graph-theory, mcl

I'm trying to cluster a graph dataset using Markov Clustering Algorithm in R. 
I've followed thorugh so many tutorials including

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849835/how-to-calculate-adjacency-matrices-in-r), [this](https://ruhansa.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/the-markov-cluster-algorithmmcl-on-r/) and many others.

My dataset looks like this:

```
   V1 V2 V3
1   0  1  1
2   0  2  1
3   1  2  1
4   2  3  2
5   2  4  2
6   2  5  3
7   3  6  4
8   3  7  5
9   3  8  5
10  4  9  6
11  4 10  4
12  4 11  5
13  4 12  7
14  4 13  4
```

V1 and V2 are nodes and V3 is weight of the connection.

Every tutorial mentions creating an adjacent matrix. When I try their code, it always throws out of bound errors. 
I'm assuming this is due to different parameters for columns and rows. But nothing really makes sense.

Even creating a Adjacent matrix is challenging, let alone implementing MCL.

Any ideas? What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
 df <- read.table(header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, text="     V1      V2     V3
 1   0  1  1
    2   0  2  1
    3   1  2  1
    4   2  3  2
    5   2  4  2
    6   2  5  3
    7   3  6  4
    8   3  7  5
    9   3  8  5
    10  4  9  6
    11  4 10  4
    12  4 11  5
    13  4 12  7
    14  4 13  4")
```

include library reshape2:

```
require(reshape2)
```

Now using reshape to convert it to adjacent table:

```
m <- as.matrix(dcast(df, V1 ~ V2, value.var = "V3", fill=0))
```

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849835/how-to-calculate-adjacency-matrices-in-r) tutorial. But at the end of

```
m <- as.matrix(dcast(df, V1 ~ V2, value.var = "V3", fill=0)),
```

there is another parameter `[,2:3]` in the tutorial. The tutorial uses square matrix to begin with. When I try to run the next command:

```
row.names(m) <- colnames(m)
```

it throws errors showing:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
```

`length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`

Comment: what is 4 10? both are nodes?

Comment: can you post the error and the code that you are trying

Comment: @Hardikgupta, yes,both are nodes

Comment: you get this error because now in matrix `m` you have 5 rows, whereas there are 13 columns. That's why dimension mismatch

Comment: elements present in V1 and V2 are not consistent, in the sense unique elements present in both columns is not consistent. Node 10,11 etc are not present in V1 and hence there are lesser number of elements and hence mismatch

Comment: you can create the adjacency matrix using graph tools: `library(igraph) ; as_adj(graph_from_data_frame(df), attr="V3", sparse=FALSE)`